# TeamCity build failed

Tags: github, build, teamcity

We are creating package of our product on TeamCity, connected with GitHub.
I can access the GitHub with credentials, I can access the TeamCity server too. But when I am trying to build the project then it is failing. It used to run smoothly but its failing for last few weeks. Attaching screen capture of the error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that your TeamCity agent isn't able to access the internet?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes there was problem with Internet connection and Other issue was Fetch was using http:// and not https://.